# How to resolve this kind of query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a Mysql database.

**PACKAGES:**

```
ID (auto_increment)
CATEGORY (INT)
NAME (VARCHAR)
EXPIRY (VARCHAR)
VISIBLE (TINYINT)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
1 | 1 | Package AAA_1 | INTERVAL 7 DAY  | 1
2 | 2 | Package BBB_1 | INTERVAL 1 YEAR | 1
3 | 1 | Packaga AAA_2 | INTERVAL 14 DAY | 1
```

**SUBSCRIPTIONS:**

```
id (auto_increment)
id_user (INT)
id_package (INT) // It points to packages.id
date (DATETIME)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 2012-01-06 00:04:18
```

My problem is that a sigle user can have more subscriptions for the same package (because when a subscription expiry there will be a new subscription and I need to track all the previous subscription to know the "Story" of each user)

Now, I have to create a query to extract all the packages (where `packages.visible=1` and `ORDER BY packages.category`) and

CHECK

What is the real expiration of that user package.

as you see I have `subscriptions.date` (it is the date when the user does the subscription), then i have to add at this date the `packages.expiry` to know the DATE of the real expiration. Obviously I ONLY have to add subscription.date + package.expiry to the **LAST** subscription the user made of that specific package.

**EDIT:**

Obviously I have to pass to this query the ID of the user I would like to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select statement will give you the information you need, but because the package expiry field appears to be free-form text I don't think there's a way to add it to the last subscription date.

```
SELECT subscriptions.id_user, packages.name, MAX(subscriptions.date), packages.expiry
FROM subscriptions JOIN packages ON subscriptions.id_package = packages.id
WHERE packages.visible = 1
GROUP BY subscriptions.id_user, subscriptions.id_package
ORDER BY packages.category
```